# What is the correct header value to bypass MDS HTTP authentication?

Tags: blackberry

I found this article: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Issues-with-BlackBerry-MDS-Connection-Service-when-using-Pre/ta-p/495706

It says that starting from BlackBerry Enterprise Server 4.1.7 you can add x-rim-authentication-passthrough header to bypass MDS HTTP authentication per request.

Which value should I set for this header? My wild guesses so-far that haven't worked are:

```
//httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication-passthrough", "true");
//httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication-passthrough", "enabled");
//httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication-passthrough", "");
//httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication", "passthrough");
//httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication-passthrough", "arghhh");
//httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication-passthrough", "where the hell is the documentation?");
//httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication-passthrough", "put the lime in the coconut");
```

Comment: You could at least fix your link when copying and pasting from the blackberry forum: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/x-rim-authentication-passthrough-header-to-bypass-MDS-HTTP/m-p/1142443

Comment: Thanks, link fixed. What a coincidence, another rayvahey asked the same question over there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-authentication-passthrough", "true");
```

I must have messed something up the first time around. I never did find the documentation, I got the answer from someone at RIM.