# Is there a javascript or response header to log an NTLM user out in a browser?

Tags: authentication, blackberry, credentials, ntlm

I've written a couple of asp .net HTML applications designed for use on small blackberry devices. The BB OS versions are from 4.6 to 5.0.

The sites use Windows authentication to log the user in. Is there a way to allow the user to logout of the applications so that any further revisit will prompt them for the NTLM credentials again?

Thanks,

Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an MDS proxy it's that handling the NTLM authentication to the end server. You will likely be using basic authentication between the phone and proxy.

There isn't an MDS API that will tell it to re-authenticate. The best you can do via MDS is bypass authentication all together but then you will need to manage NTLM yourself:

[What is the correct header value to bypass MDS HTTP authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317956/what-is-the-correct-header-value-to-bypass-mds-http-authentication)

Another option is to write your own logout API on your .NET application which deletes your session cookie. That way MDS will be forced to re-negotiate NTLM at the next attempt.

**note:** The bypass option is available in Enterprise Server 4.1.7 and above, it's not available in the simulator.